# Why I can not see image on canvas?

Tags: javascript

I am very very new at javascript. In first minute I have first problem which is I can not see image on canvas. I assume getContext function not working properly. I make lots of search but I can't find any solution. Here my simple code:

```
let cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx);


let bg = new Image();


bg.src = "images/bg.png";


function draw() { 

    ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0);
}

draw();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61404533/canvas-javascript-drawimage-method/61404987#61404987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load

```js
let cvs = document.getElementById("canvas")
let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d")
let bg = new Image()
bg.src = "https://picsum.photos/300/200"
bg.addEventListener('load', () => {
  ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0)
})
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Answer working correctly but I want to add src in my images folder not url. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yeah sure just write the local src. I used an external URL just for the sake of a working demo :)